# Swift 2d array minimum

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, math

I have an 2d array like this:

```
let array= [ [0,2], [4,5], [4,1], [0,4] ]
```

and I'd like to get **ONE** element thats `0.` index is the smallest in the array.

Result should be this:

```
let result = [0,2] // not also [0,4] because just the first one
```

This is what I've tried so far but obviously this is not a working solution `:p`

```
let result = array.filter { $0[1].map { return $0.min() } }
```

Thanks in advance, jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Array.min` then compare the first element of the nested arrays. `min` will return the first element in the original array that fits the minimum function in the closure in case there were several minima.

```
let array = [ [0,2], [4,5], [4,1], [0,4] ]
let result = array.min(by: {$0.first! < $1.first!}) //[0,2]
```